# Forced selfmate in n-moves

Tags: chess, open-ended, selfmate

> I assume most people on PSE know a bit of chess

With white to move, this is checkmate (1. Qb7#):

[image: Checkmate]

That's boring. Let's try something more interesting. With black to move, black can FORCE white to checkmate (1... Qxb7+ 2. Qxb7#):

[image: Force checkmate]

We can go another step. In this position, white can force black to force white to checkmate (1. Qxb7+ Qxb7+ 2. Qxb7#):

[image: Force forcing checkmate]

I'm going to call this a forced checkmate in 2 (an abuse of traditional problems where you have to force checkmate in 2).

I can do forced checkmate in 12 (1... Qxb7+ 2. Qxb7+ Qxb7+ 3. Qxb7+ Qxb7+ 4. Qxb7+ Qxb7+ 5. Qxb7+ Qxb7+ 6. Qxb7+ Qxb7+ 7. Qxb7#):

[image: Forced checkmate in 12]

> ## Can you do better?

**NOTES:**

- There must be *exactly* one line after the first move, otherwise it is not strictly forced and I have to think too much.
- The position must be theoretically possible (so not 10 queens of one colour, 11 bishops of one colour, etc.)

Comment: @humn you can just put s (small), m (medium), l (large and default), or h (huge) after the 5 letter imgur address. m works best for me

Comment: This puzzle must have been fun to concoct, amounting to the creation/solution of these examples and others along the way

Comment: related, cross-site dupe: http://chess.stackexchange.com/q/8789/9025

Comment: @HerbWolfe I've got 15 half-moves - so I want a better answer. If someone wants, they can submit my solution, I don't mind. But I want to ask the question in front of a bigger community, with a target to beat.

Comment: This type of challenge is already fairly well known, and called a [selfmate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selfmate). Some simple Web searches failed to turn up a discussion of particularly long ones (there's a selfmate in 13 full moves [as entry #8 on this page](http://www.theproblemist.org/what-are-chess-problems/29-selfmates), but no suggestion that it's anywhere near the record). That might serve as a good starting point for people looking for existing solutions that might already be out there.

Comment: @ais523 But selfmates can have multiple branches. Also, selfmates would only be forced checkmate in (odd #).

Comment: Actually, something that's unclear in the question: is White trying to give Black a long sequence of forced moves that lead to White's mate (which is a restriction of selfmates, but perhaps a fairly minor one)? Or is White trying to find a move that forces *both players* down a single line that eventually leads to checkmate?

Comment: @ais523 Your latter option.

Comment: I have a question - why not 2 ... Qbxb7?

Comment: Does it require a check every move? Or just as long as it's mate at the end with only one possible line apart from the first move (optionally).

Comment: @DrXorile Just one possible line.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I can do better:

> I can do forced checkmate in 13 (1... Qbxb7+ 2. Qxb7+ Qxb7+ 3. Qxb7+ Qxb7+ 4. Qxb7+ Qxb7+ 5. Qxb7+ Qxb7+ 6. Qxb7+ Qxb7+ 7. Qxb7 Qxb7#):
>  [image]

(sorry for stealing your answer)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a new record of **16 moves** that is a slight modification of a position made by Bernd Schwarzkopf and Karl Scherer in Feensnach 1980 on page 13. A PDF can be found [here](http://problem64.beda.cz/silo/feenschach51_1980.pdf).

[image]

FEN: QKN4r/nRRRRRRr/kq6/p1q1R3/1P1q1b2/4q3/5q2/1r4q1 w KQkq - 0 1

Answer (score 2):

In this position that I composed long ago (this position is legal), every move is completely forced and it is checkmate in

> !8 moves (15 ply):
>   1. Qxc7+ Qxc7+ 2. Qxc7+ Qxc7+ 3. Qxc7+ Qxc7+ 4. Bxc7+ Kb7+ 5. Bb8+ Qxe7+ 6. Qxe7+ Qxe7+ 7. Qxe7+ Qxe7+ 8. Rxe7#
>
> [image]

Comment: I alrighty have you beat: sorry!

Comment: And this question is about a **selfmate**:You could add in the black queen moving to her square for 16 like mine got a tie.

Comment: Also, funnily enough, before I even knew you were on SE just now, I cited your chess com forum post with this position in this CSE question, =D: https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/8789/15543

Comment: Hah that's really interesting. Yes I could place the black queen on b7 for a selfmate but I just posted the position as originally intended (all moves forced). It was really cool to see the 16 ply forced checkmate, maybe I'll try to tie that one day :)